# Proving that a given $u$ is a solution to $u_{tt} = c^2 u_{xx}.$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Proving that a given $u$ is a solution to $u_{tt} = c^2 u_{xx}.$

The question asks me to prove that $$u(x,t) = F(ct + x) + G(ct -x),$$ is a solution of the above equation on condition that we know that $F$ and $G$ are twice differentiable functions on $[0,L]$

**My attempt:**

I calculated $u_{tt} = c^2 (\partial^2F/\partial t^2 + \partial^2G/\partial t^2 )$, and $u_{xx} = (\partial^2F/\partial x^2 + \partial^2G/\partial x^2 )$, but I do not know what next should I do, the problem is that I have two different differentiations one with respect to $t$ and the other with respect to $x$ and I do not know how they can be cancelled with each other to satisfy the above equation, could anyone help me in this please?

Comment: Here's a hint: Applying the chain rule properly, we get $$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}F(ct+x) = cF'(ct+x).$$ Note that we get an $F'$ when we differentiate with respect to either variable. Typically this is applied to the wave equation over all of $\mathbb R$, however.

Comment: you mean that my application for the chain rule is incorrect? @MarkMcClure

Comment: Not quite wrong -  it's incomplete.

Comment: so how can I look at the function so that my application to the chain rule becomes complete?@MarkMcClure ..... I think I applied it as you explained above

Comment: Then, where is your $F'$ or $G'$??

Comment: I have written it above below the subtitle my trial @MarkMcClure

Comment: What has been given to you as an exercice is usually part of a lecture which shows that $u(x,t)$ is **the** general solution of the wave equation ; see for example http://web.mit.edu/fluids-modules/waves/www/material/chap-2.pdf

Comment: @JeanMarie I have looked at the pdf but could not find an answer to my question

Comment: @MarkMcClure could you give me more details please?

Comment: In the document, you see what I say in the first page formula (1.2) ; they say that the computation is very easy... which is true... When you speak of cancellation, you are wrong, there is no cancellation.

Comment: @hopefully I guess I could reiterate what I already said. I don't see an $F'$ in your work. I do see $\partial^2 F/\partial x^2$ but partial derivatives are a different thing. $F'$ denotes the ordinary derivative of $F$, which is a function of one variable; $\partial F/\partial x$ denotes the partial derivative of $F(ct+x)$ with respect to $x$. Note that $F(ct+x)$ is a function of the two variables $x$ and $t$. You should try to express your partial derivatives of $F(ct+x)$ in terms of the ordinary derivatives of $F$.

Comment: okay ..so if I have $F(u)$ and $u(x,t )$ then $dF/dt = \partial F/ \partial u$ x $\partial u/ \partial t$ ... is that what you  mean @MarkMcClure

Comment: @hopefully Well, I'd write $\partial F/\partial t = F'(u(x,t))\times \partial u/\partial t$, but yeah.

Comment: you mean that the dash above the $F$ refers to a total derivative?@MarkMcClure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $p = ct + x$ and $q = ct-x$. Then $F(p)$ and $G(q)$ are functions of a single variable.

By the multivariable chain rule we have

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial F}{\partial x} &= \frac{dF}{dp}\frac{\partial p}{\partial x} = \frac{dF}{dp} \\
\frac{\partial F}{\partial t} &= \frac{dF}{dp}\frac{\partial p}{\partial t} = c\frac{dF}{dp}
\end{align}

Do this a second time

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial x^2} &= \frac{d^2F}{dp^2} \\
\frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial t^2} &= c^2\frac{d^2F}{dp^2}
\end{align}

which means $F$ satisfies the original PDE. The same logic goes for $G$.

By linearity, $u=F+G$ is also a solution.

Comment: I'm sorry but you hide (small) issues : "The same logic goes for G" : not exactly because a "-" sign occurs with the first differentiation wrt $x$,  then is cancelled by a second "-" sign at the second differentiation...

Comment: @JeanMarie Are you really going nitpick that? I didn't say it was exactly the same, just that if you apply the same chain rule, $G$ also satisfies. It's left to OP to figure out the details.